# Logging out of community on page load

Tags: apex, javascript

My problem is when `/secur/logout.jsp` is executed it goes to login page. If user hit the back button it is going back to the previous page which should not happen.

The following code is called on load of my VF page:

```
    public apexClassName()
    {
        if(UserInfo.getUserType() != 'Guest')
            logoutCommunity();
    }
    global PageReference logoutCommunity()
    {
        return new PageReference('/secur/logout.jsp');
    }
```

Thanks,
IRaj.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a requirement but rather a way to accomplish a functional requirement.  What is the functional requirement?

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement?  Is the apex class a Visualforce Page controller?

Comment: Hi, Phil and Jim thanks for you reply. I need to call this method on VF page load `code` public constructor()
    {
        System.debug(' User Logged in is > '+ UserInfo.getUserType());
        if(UserInfo.getUserType() != 'Guest')
            logoutCommunity();
    }
    

    global PageReference logoutCommunity()
    {
        return new PageReference('/secur/logout.jsp');
    }
    `code`  Which is not working for me.

Comment: Where does the javascript come into play?  Calling the code on page load?  Since you've defined this code in a constructor it is already executed on page load.  I would wager your `System.debug` is getting logged, but the logging out does not work in that context.

Comment: Hi @PhilRymek Im able to see the debug log. 12:56:14.106 (106657189)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG| User Logged in is > CspLitePortal

Comment: Why should hitting back not work?  Isn't a guest user unauthenticated, so hitting back after "logging out" would still grant you site access?

Answer (score 2):

The same question was asked in the discussion forum: [What does "/secur/logout.jsp" do? How to redirect to a custom page after logout](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008y7fIAA)

The answer is: you have to use the url parameter "retUrl".

e.g.

```
/secur/logout.jsp?retUrl=YourLoginpageURL
```

Since W15 the implementation of custom logout pages is possible:

> Add Custom Login, Logout, and Self-Registration Pages
>
> Previously, communities allowed you to customize the standard login and self-registration page for your community. You can now override this page with a Site.com or Visualforce page in one of two ways:
>
> - Specify a custom login page in the community’s Administration Settings in the Login & Registration section.
> - Add a custom login page while selecting a community template in the Community Designer.
>     Custom login pages created using the Community Designer are automatically associated with the community. The URLs for these pages display in the Login & Registration settings in the community’s Administration Settings.
>
> [- Release Notes W15](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_networks_custom_pages.htm)

Answer (score 0):

@JimRae and @Christian Deckert thanks for your help. I got the answer for my question.

```
global PageReference logoutCommunity(){
        if(UserInfo.getUserType() != 'Guest')
        {
            PageReference logoutPage = new
                     PageReference(Site.getBaseSecureUrl()+'/secur/logout.jsp');
            logoutPage.setRedirect(true);
            return logoutPage;}
        }
        return null;
  }
```

Thanks,

IRaj